# Eagle CAD: method of re-linking schematic and board?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I've accidentally lost the sync between my schematic and board, with Eagle CAD giving me the following error:

> Board and schematic are not consistent!
>   No forward-/backannotation will be performed!

Is there a method of re-linking the two?  I had very little work invested in the board layout so a method of linking the schematic to a new board file would also be helpful.

Comment: If you close everything then rename or delete the .brd file, you can start again by creating a new board from the schematic.

Comment: @RogerRowland thanks for the hint, in my particular case this is exactly the sort of hint I was looking for, although I think the more general solution is given by Oleg below.  For posterity I would note that the action to create a new board from the schematic can be found in the "actions" toolbar in a button with the description "generate/switch to board".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From schematic run ERC. Consistency errors will be at the top. Fix the errors by removing parts, nets, etc. that causes them then try to switch to layout and back. Repeat until the error message disappears.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, some versions of Eagle generate .b#1, .b#2 and .s#1, .s#2 files which are backups. If you rename the extension to .brd and .sch you can go back a few steps and hopefully recover what you lost.

Comment: this worked for me